# What is the best way to create a mobile optimized PDF from Word (or other app)?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I sometimes need to make user manuals, and usually used Word or powerpoint and sent the users PDFs.

**The problem is that almost all users read PDFs on their phone these days, and a normal PDF is of course awful for mobile sized screens.**

Surprisingly, I can't find much info on how to deal with this problem.

It looks like in Microsoft Word you can set a custom page size, and set it to continous instead of pages. Is this a good way to do this? If so, what is a good page size to use that will look good on most phones?

Are there other software that I should look into?

- Yes, I know it would probably be best to make a website. In this case it's not possible because that requires a server and is much more complicated and also:
- I want it to be PDF because it's important that the layout looks the same for everyone. Eg. when the text says "as shown on the photo to the right" I need to be sure that photo is to the right...

Answer (score 2):

A few things here:

Ideally what you want is some media with a resposive format where the layout automatically adapts to the phone screen size. This currently exisits for websites (which you don't want to use) but not for PDFs.

There is however the so called [Liquid Mode](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobat/android/en/lmode.html) in the free Adobe Acrobat Reader which tries to immitate this automatically without the creator having to edit any resposiveness settings. But I honestly don't like this mode as the user will not be able to properly get the structure of the document anymore.

Now you could of course take your approach and create a PDF that is optimized for mobile phones, but in that case, you almost need a second PDF for standard desktop users. Because if you display the mobile-optimized PDF on a computer, either the whole page will be super small on the computer or if the user zooms in, the letter will be super huge.
If you really want to take that approach, then the best option is to still use a standard full-page format (e.g. Letter format or A4 format) and simply increase the text-size and the sizes of the graphic elements. If you structure your Word document (that you can later export as a PDF) thoughtfully (e.g. set image position aligned to right margin, so that it always sticks to the right margin no matter of its size), then you can use the same document fairly easily to create one desktop PDF version and one mobile version by [resizing all text relatively](https://youtu.be/pKWhrfpoimQ). Note that you will have to resize images manually but you can speed up this process by [resizing all images at once with a macro](https://youtu.be/Tf4mZTr2q04).

Hope this gives you a few ideas on how to tackle this topic (if you really want to create a special mobile friendly version).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. In my case, it's not a problem that the PDF is not optimized for Desktop. The PDF consists mostly of screenshots from phones, so pages are narrow.
I also don't need the document to be responsive. I prefer PDF since I know the layout will be the same for every device.